# How to replace only the Nth occurrence of a pattern in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I replace the *N*th (for example, the third) occurrence
of a string (or pattern) in a file using the `sed` command? 
I do mean the *N*th occurrence in the file,
not the *N*th occurrence in a line
or the first occurrence in the *N*th matching line. 
There may be multiple occurrences in a line,
and an occurrence (a match) might be a partial word.

Example:

Change only the third occurrence of `is` to `us` in the file.

My input file contains:

```
hai this is linux.
hai this is unix.
hai this is mac.
hai this is unchanged.
```

The expected output is:

```
hai this is linux.
hai thus is unix.
hai this is mac.
hai this is unchanged.
```

Note that “this” has been replaced by “th***us”*** in the second line.

Comment: `sed` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan:  Note, FYI, that I reverted your edit to this question.

Answer (score 12):

It's a lot easier done with `perl`.

To change the 3<sup>rd</sup> occurrence:

```
perl -pe 's{is}{++$n == 3 ? "us" : $&}ge'
```

To change every 3<sup>rd</sup> occurrence:

```
perl -pe 's{is}{++$n % 3 ? $& : "us"}ge'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed` for that if previously newlines are replaced to any other characters, e.g.:

```
tr '\n' '\000' | sed 's/is/us/3' | tr '\000' '\n'
```

And the same with pure (GNU) `sed`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\x0/g;s/is/us/3;s/\x0/\n/g'
```

<sub>(`sed` newline replacement shamelessly stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/4488514)</sub>

Comment: If you're going to use GNU `sed` specific syntax, you might as well use `sed -z 's/is/us/3'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `-z` must be some brand new feature, my `GNU sed version 4.2.1` doesn't know anything about this option.

Comment: Added in 4.2.2 (2012). In your second solution, you don't need the conversion to `\x0` step.

Comment: Sorry about the edit. I had not seen the original version of the question and someone had misunderstood it and edited the wrong line. I reverted to the previous version.

Comment: This worked best in situation where there were no \n and it was a bash array requiring replacing of element separator data entered by user.

Answer (score 3):

When the replacement string occurs only once per line, you can combine different utilities.
When the input is in the file "input" and you are replacing " is " by " us ", you can use

```
LINENR=$(cat input | grep -n " is " | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1)
cat input | sed ${LINENR}' s/ is / us /'
```

Comment: In the example in the question, there are more than one `is` per line.

Comment: I thought you were looking for " is " with spaces. I could edit my answer with the tr command like @jimmij used, but my solution would become far inferiour to his.

Comment: I'm not the asker :). I thought the same thing, which is why I had upvoted your answer, but if you look at the original version of the question (click on the "Edited X minutes ago" link) you'll see that the OP expected the _is_ in _this_ to be changed to _thus_. By the way, there is [no need for cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) there.

Answer (score 2):

The script below (using *GNU* `sed` syntax) is usable for inplace editing not for output because it stop print lines after desired substitution:

```
sed -i '/is/{: 1 ; /\(.*is\)\{3\}/!{N;b1} ; s/is/us/3 ; q}' text.file
```

If your like [choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13792/choroba) decision you can modify above to

```
sed '/is/{:1 ; /\(.*is\)\{3\}/!{N;b1} ; s/is/us/3 ; :2 ; n ; $!b2}' text.file
```

which outputs all lines

Or you have to put all lines in pattern space (in memory so be careful with size limitation) and do substitution

```
sed ': 1 ; N ; $!b1 ; s/is/us/3 ' text.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p='[:punct:]' s='[:space:]'
sed -Ee'1!{/\n/!b' -e\}            \
     -e's/(\n*)(.*)/ \2 \1/'       \
     -e"s/is[$p]?[$s]/\n&/g"       \
     -e"s/([^$s])\n/\1/g;1G"       \
-e:c -e"s/\ni(.* )\n{3}/u\1/"      \
     -e"/\n$/!s/\n//g;/\ni/G"      \
     -e's//i/;//tc'                \
     -e's/^ (.*) /\1/;P;$d;N;D'
```

That bit of `sed` just carries a tally of `is` occurrences from one line to the next. It should reliably handle as many `is`es per line as you throw at it, and it doesn't need to buffer old lines while it does - it just retains a single newline character for every `is` that it encounters which is not a part of another word.

The upshot is it will modify only the third occurrence in a file - and it will carry counts per line. So if a file looks like:

```
1. is is isis
2. is does
```

...it will print...

```
1. is is isis
2. us does
```

It first handles edge cases by inserting a space at the head and tail of every line. This makes word boundaries a little easier to ascertain.

It next looks for valid `is`es by inserting a `\n`ewline before all occurrences of `is` that immediately precede zero or one punctuation characters followed by a space.  It does another pass and removes all `\n`ewlines that are immediately preceded by a not-space character. This markers left behind will match `is.` and `is` but not `this` or `?is`.

It next gathers each marker to the tail of the string - for every `\ni` match on a line it appends a `\n`ewline to the tail of the string and replaces it with with either `i` or `u`. If there are 3 `\n`ewlines in a row gathered at the tail of the string then it uses the u - else the i. The first time a u is used is also the last - the replacement sets off an infinite loop that boils down to `get line, print line, get line, print line,` and so on.

At the end of each try loop cycle it cleans up the inserted spaces, prints only up to the first occurring newline in pattern space, and goes again.

I'll add in a `l`ook command at the head of the loop like:

```
l; s/\ni(.* )\n{9}/u\1/...
```

...and take a look at what it does as it works with this input:

```
hai this is linux.
hai this is unix.


hai this is mac.
hai this is unchanged is.
```

...so here's what it does:

```
 hai this \nis linux. \n$        #behind the scenes
hai this is linux.               #actually printed
 hai this \nis unix. \n\n$       #it builds the marker string
hai this is unix.
  \n\n\n$                        #only for lines matching the

  \n\n\n$                        #pattern - and not otherwise.

 hai this \nis mac. \n\n\n$      #here's the match - 3 ises so far in file.
hai this us mac.                 #printed
hai this is unchanged is.        #no look here - this line is never evaled
```

It makes more sense maybe with more `is`es per line:

```
nthword()(  p='[:punct:]' s='[:space:]'         
    sed -e '1!{/\n/!b' -e\}             \
        -e 's/\(\n*\)\(.*\)/ \2 \1/'    \
        -e "s/$1[$p]\{0,1\}[$s]/\n&/g"  \
        -e "s/\([^$s]\)\n/\1/g;1G;:c"   \
        -e "${dbg+l;}s/\n$1\(.* \)\n\{$3\}/$2\1/" \
        -e '/\n$/!s/\n//g;/\n'"$1/G"    \
        -e "s//$1/;//tc" -e 's/^ \(.*\) /\1/'     \
        -e 'P;$d;N;D'
)
```

That's practically the same thing but written w/ POSIX BRE and rudimentary argument handling.

```
 printf 'is is. is? this is%.0s\n' {1..4}  | nthword is us 12
```

...gets...

```
is is. is? this is
is is. is? this is
is is. is? this us
is is. is? this is
```

...and if I enable `${dbg}`:

```
printf 'is is. is? this is%.0s\n' {1..4}  | 
dbg=1 nthword is us 12
```

...we can watch it iterate...

```
 \nis \nis. \nis? this \nis \n$
 is \nis. \nis? this \nis \n\n$
 is is. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n$
 is is. is? this \nis \n\n\n\n$
is is. is? this is
 \nis \nis. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n$
 is \nis. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n$
 is is. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
 is is. is? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
is is. is? this is
 \nis \nis. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
 is \nis. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
 is is. \nis? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
 is is. is? this \nis \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$
is is. is? this us
is is. is? this is
```

Comment: Did you realize your example says "isis"?

Comment: @flarn2006 - im pretty sure it says is is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a logical solution that uses `sed` and `tr` but must be written in a script for it to work. The code below replaces every **3rd occurrence** of the word specified in the `sed` command. Replace `i=3` with `i=n` to make this work for any `n`.

## Code:

```
# replace new lines with '^' character to get everything onto a single line
tr '\n' '^' < input.txt > output.txt

# count number of occurrences of the word to be replaced
num=`grep -o "apple" "output.txt" | wc -l`

# in successive iterations, replace the i + (n-1)th occurrence
n=3
i=3
while [ $i -le $num ]
do
    sed -i '' "s/apple/lemon/${i}" 'output.txt'
    i=$(( i + (n-1) ))
done

# replace the '^' back to new line character
tr '^' '\n' < output.txt > tmp && mv tmp output.txt
```

## Why this works:

Suppose the text file is `a b b b b a c a d a b b b a b e b z b s b a b`.

- When n = 2: we want to replace every second occurrence of `b`.

  - `a b b b b a c a d a b b b a b e b z b s b a b`
    `. . ^ . ^ . . . . . . ^ . . ^ . . . ^ . ^ . ^`
  - First we replace the 2nd occurrence, then the 3rd occurrence, then the 4th, 5th, and so on. Count in the sequence shown above to see this for yourself.
- When n = 3: we want to replace every third occurrence of `b`.

  - `a b b b b a c a d a b b b a b e b z b s b a b`
    `. . . ^ . . . . . . . ^ . . . . ^ . . . . . ^`
  - First we replace the 3rd occurrence, then the 5th, then the 7th, 9th, 11th, and so on.
- When n = 4: we want to replace every third occurrence of `b`.

  - First we replace the 4th occurrence, then 7th, then 10th, 13th, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed with -z option to define the occurrence you want to replace.

```
sed -i -z "s/is/us/3" pom.xml your.file
```

Comment: (1) You are *allowed* to copy a solution that somebody else already posted as a comment, and post it as an answer, but you should (a) give credit to the original author, (b) add something, like an explanation, *or, ideally, **both**.*  (2) What is `pom.xml`?